# yum install a particular version

Tags: linux, php, centos, yum

I am currently using centOS 5.2 I want to install `php 5.3.3`. how do I install using yum?

Answer (score 3):

You have to first add a repository that  has  PHP 5.3.
In this case you can use the [webtatic](http://www.webtatic.com/) one

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
```

Then execute the following:

```
yum update
```

Install PHP:

```
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php
```

Answer (score 2):

To install a specific version, just ask to yum to install the package with its **full** name.

For example, if the fullname of php-5.3.3 is 'php-5.3.3-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm' :

```
yum install php-5.3.3-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

For more information, you can read this small article : http://www.zulius.com/how-to/yum-install-specific-package-version

Comment: @SeyZ Thanks a lot. I tried it did not work on the box.

Comment: I'm not on a yum package manager so I can't test for you. Are you sure that the name of the package is correct and is the full name ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run `yum list php` or `yum search php`?  Do you have a repository that has php 5.3.3?  CentOS 5.2 is rather old so by default it comes with an older version of PHP. I'm running 5.4 and had to find a repo that has the latest version.

I use [this](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install php-5.3.3
```

is enough